# Qual a melhor terminologia em português para os ícones "Undo" e "Redo"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Após alguma pesquisa, não encontrei uma tradução direta e de fácil compreensão para o utilizador das terminologias "undo" e "redo", utilizadas junto dos respetivos ícones.
Testámos junto de um grupo de utilizadores as seguintes terminologias: "Repetir" e "repôr ação" e não foram muito bem entendidas...
Sugestões aceitam-se! :)

Comment: Eu acho que **desfazer** e **refazer** são boas opções.

Comment: Eu até achei que **desfazer** e **refazer** já fossem padrões de fato. Bastante comum ver estes termos em softwares como editores de texto, planilhas, navegadores...

Answer (score 10):

**Undo** significa desfazer.

**Redo** significa refazer. Para melhor entendimento pode utilizar como: Refazer (última ação).

Uma pequena pesquisa no Google Tradutor pode ajudar. Bons dicionários inglês-português também podem fornecer outras alternativas.